# filter the array with two value in ionic 3

Tags: arrays, sorting, ionic-framework, filter, ionic3

I have the higher price value and lower price value. And i have a array..so now i need to filter the array between high price and low price

```
High price = 90;
low price = 20;

actual array = [
      { price: "10" },
      { price: "30" },
      { price: "40" },
      { price: "70" },
      { price: "90" },
      { price: "100" }
    ];
```

So now after filter i need only in between values.like this

```
array = [
     { price: "30" },
     { price: "40" },
     { price: "70" },
     { price: "90" }
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` method:

```js
let array = [
  { price: "10" },
  { price: "30" },
  { price: "40" },
  { price: "70" },
  { price: "90" },
  { price: "100" }
];

let highPrice = 90;
let lowPrice = 20;

const result = array.filter(s => s.price >= lowPrice && s.price <= highPrice)
console.log(result)
```